# Google function and addDomListener

Tags: jquery, google-maps-api-3

I have set code to display without an error but I'me new to this. Specially 
`addDomListener` position.

```
var GoogleMap1 = function() {

    return {

        initMap: function() {
            (function(jQuery) {

                jQuery(document).ready(function() {

                    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882, 131.044922);
                    var mapOptions = {
                        zoom: 4,
                        center: myLatlng
                    }
                    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: myLatlng,
                        map: map,
                        title: 'Hello World!'
                    });

                    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

                });

            })(jQuery);
        }

    };
}();
```

Is this correct or can be improved, specially line:   `google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);`

Reference URL for addDomListener is actually at 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-simple

Currently it will be an error and I like to avoid using solution like ddDomListener:

> Error: TypeError: element is null Line:
>   element.parentNode.removeChild(element);

Need help.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to add a callback to the google scripts which runs the initialized function.

```
<script type="text/javascript"
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&callback=initialize"></script>
```

Then create the initialize function and attach it to the `window object`

```
var map;
window.initialize  = function () {
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882,131.044922);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 4,
    center: myLatlng
 }
 map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatlng,
      map: map,
      title: 'Hello World!'
  });
}
```

Note the map is initialized outside the function so it can be used later on.
With this, there is no need to specify an event to listen to.
Once the google maps scripts load completely, it calls the callback function.